# Overriding attributes of SharedAssemblyInfo with AssemblyInfo

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, .net-assembly

I am using a shared assembly info file (GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs) for multiple projects in a solution, which is "Add[ed] As Link" to each project. Each project has in addition its own AssemblyInfo.cs to add attributes that are not common to all projects. Duplicated attributes, also among both files, are not allowed.

One of the projects needs to have one of the attributes that are shared among the others differently, but share the rest. Is it possible, and how, to have an attribute in the AssemblyInfo.cs override the same attribute in the GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs? Or do I have to remove the attribute from the shared file and add it to all of the projects individually, even if all except one are the same?

In particular, the attribute that is shared among all except the one project is:

```
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]
```

One of the projects needs to have `[assembly: ComVisible(true)]`, which causes the conflict of duplicate attributes. To clarify, what I am looking for is something like `[assembly: @override ComVisible(true)]`, if it exists, however I didn't find anything like that yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest answer to this is that your shared assembly info should only contain the items that are identical for all projects.

Any item that needs different values must be defined in the local assembly info, not the shared one.

Alternatively, you could use a build task to generate the assembly info files in more hierarchical / inheritable way.

Comment: Unfortunately there are about 40 projects that all use the same attributes, until that one came that needs to change one of them. I was hoping, since using a shared AssemblyInfo seems to be a common practice, that there might exist something like a compiler directive.

Comment: The solution for you would be to generate the Assembly Info for each project using a build step. AssemblyInfo.cs is not hierarchical out of the box, so it won't allow you to override a value.

Comment: We ended up using a script as part of the build process that copies the attributes from the GlobalAssemblyInfo to this one exceptional AssemblyInfo before compilation. Not elegant, but it works.

Comment: Good stuff - although these build steps can seem inelegant, once you have something that works it can be refined. I'm glad you got it working.